# ¿Cómo ejecutar un Trigger en SQL solo si se cumple una condición?

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, condiciones, trigger

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Quiero ejecutar un trigger solo si se cumple una condición pero hasta el momento no el logrado conseguirlo.

El trigger deberia dispararse cuando algunas de las columnas de interés hallan sufrido cambios. Es posible hacerlo?  aquí les de dejo mi código SQL:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_HISTORIAL_EMPLEADO

ON EMPLEADO FOR UPDATE
AS
--- LA BUSQUEDA Y ACTUALIZACION SE HACE EN BASE AL CODIGO DE REGISTRO DE LA TABLE DE EMPLEADOS
DECLARE @CODEMPLEADO INT
SELECT @CODEMPLEADO = COD_EMPLEADO FROM DELETED


DECLARE @NOMBREEMPLEADO VARCHAR (100)
SELECT @NOMBREEMPLEADO = CONCAT(PRIMER_NOMBRE,' ',SEGUNDO_NOMBRE,' ',PRIMER_APELLIDO,' ',SEGUNDO_APELLIO) FROM DELETED

DECLARE @USUARIORESPONSABLE VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @NOMBREPC VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @TIPOACTUALIZACION VARCHAR(100) = 'ACTUALIZACION DE DATOS'
SELECT @USUARIORESPONSABLE = USUARIO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @USUARIORESPONSABLE = COD_USUARIO FROM USUARIO WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO=@USUARIORESPONSABLE
SELECT @NOMBREPC = NOMBRE_PC FROM INSERTED

--VARIBLES QUE CONTIENEN LOS DATOS ACTUALES DE LA TABLA EMPLEADOS ANTES DE SER MODIFICADOS

DECLARE @ESTADOEMPLEADO_ACTUAL VARCHAR (20)
DECLARE @TIPOID_ACTUAL VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @NUMEROID_ACTUAL VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @CIUDADEXP_ACTUAL VARCHAR (200)
DECLARE @FECHAEXP_ACTUAL DATE
DECLARE @FECHAI_ACTUAL DATE
DECLARE @FECHAR_ACTUAL DATE
DECLARE @TIPOCONTRATO_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @SALARIO_ACTUAL DECIMAL
DECLARE @TIPOLABORES_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @DEPENDENCIA_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @CARGO_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @SALUD_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @PENSION_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @ARL_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @CAJA_ACTUAL VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @FECHA_ACTUALIZACION_LAB DATE

--VARIBLES DONDE SE ALMACENARAN LOS NUEVOS DATOS ACTUALIZADOS EN CADA COLUMNA

DECLARE @ESTADOEMPLEADO_NUEVO VARCHAR (20)
DECLARE @TIPOID_NUEVO VARCHAR(3)
DECLARE @NUMEROID_NUEVO VARCHAR (50)
DECLARE @CIUDADEXP_NUEVO VARCHAR (200)
DECLARE @FECHAEXP_NUEVO DATE
DECLARE @FECHAI_NUEVO DATE
DECLARE @FECHAR_NUEVO DATE
DECLARE @TIPOCONTRATO_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @SALARIO_NUEVO DECIMAL
DECLARE @TIPOLABORES_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @DEPENDENCIA_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @CARGO_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @SALUD_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @PENSION_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @ARL_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)
DECLARE @CAJA_NUEVO VARCHAR (100)

---SE CARGAN LAS COLUMNAS CON SU INFORMACION ORIGINAL (ANTES DE SER ACTUALIZADOS)
SELECT @TIPOID_ACTUAL= TIPO_DOCUMENTO FROM DELETED
SELECT @NUMEROID_ACTUAL = NUM_DOCUMENTO FROM DELETED
SELECT @CIUDADEXP_ACTUAL = LUGAR_EXP FROM DELETED
SELECT @FECHAEXP_ACTUAL= FECHA_EXP_DOC FROM DELETED
SELECT @FECHAI_ACTUAL = FECHA_INGRESO FROM DELETED
SELECT @FECHAR_ACTUAL = FECHA_RETIRO FROM DELETED
SELECT @TIPOCONTRATO_ACTUAL = TIPO_CONTRATO FROM DELETED
SELECT @SALARIO_ACTUAL = SALARIO FROM DELETED
SELECT @TIPOLABORES_ACTUAL = TIPO_LABOR FROM DELETED
SELECT @DEPENDENCIA_ACTUAL = DEPENDENCIA FROM DELETED
SELECT @CARGO_ACTUAL = CARGO_ACTUAL FROM DELETED
SELECT @SALUD_ACTUAL = SALUD FROM DELETED
SELECT @PENSION_ACTUAL = PENSION FROM DELETED
SELECT @ARL_ACTUAL = ARL FROM DELETED
SELECT @CAJA_ACTUAL = CAJA_COMPENSACION FROM DELETED

---SE CARGAN LAS COLUMNAS CON SU INFORMACION ACTALIZADA
SELECT @TIPOID_NUEVO= TIPO_DOCUMENTO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @NUMEROID_NUEVO = NUM_DOCUMENTO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @CIUDADEXP_NUEVO = LUGAR_EXP FROM INSERTED
SELECT @FECHAEXP_NUEVO= FECHA_EXP_DOC FROM INSERTED
SELECT @FECHAI_NUEVO = FECHA_INGRESO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @FECHAR_NUEVO = FECHA_RETIRO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @TIPOCONTRATO_NUEVO = TIPO_CONTRATO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @SALARIO_NUEVO = SALARIO FROM INSERTED
SELECT @TIPOLABORES_NUEVO = TIPO_LABOR FROM INSERTED
SELECT @DEPENDENCIA_NUEVO = DEPENDENCIA FROM INSERTED
SELECT @CARGO_NUEVO = CARGO_ACTUAL FROM INSERTED
SELECT @SALUD_NUEVO = SALUD FROM INSERTED
SELECT @PENSION_NUEVO = PENSION FROM INSERTED
SELECT @ARL_NUEVO = ARL FROM INSERTED
SELECT @CAJA_NUEVO = CAJA_COMPENSACION FROM INSERTED
SELECT @FECHA_ACTUALIZACION_LAB = FECHA_ACTUALIZACION_LABORAL FROM INSERTED

--IF @FECHAI_ACTUAL<>NULL  AND @FECHAR_NUEVO<>NULL 
--  BEGIN
--      SET @ESTADOEMPLEADO_NUEVO='ACTIVO' 
--      SET @TIPOACTUALIZACION='FECHA RETIRO'
--  END

IF (@TIPOCONTRATO_ACTUAL<>@TIPOID_NUEVO OR
    @NUMEROID_ACTUAL<>@NUMEROID_NUEVO OR
    @CIUDADEXP_ACTUAL<>@CIUDADEXP_NUEVO OR
    @FECHAEXP_ACTUAL<>@FECHAEXP_NUEVO OR
    @FECHAI_ACTUAL <> @FECHAI_NUEVO OR
    @FECHAR_ACTUAL <> @FECHAR_NUEVO OR
    @TIPOCONTRATO_ACTUAL <> @TIPOCONTRATO_NUEVO OR
    @SALARIO_ACTUAL <> @SALARIO_NUEVO OR
    @TIPOLABORES_ACTUAL <> @TIPOLABORES_NUEVO OR
    @DEPENDENCIA_ACTUAL <> @DEPENDENCIA_NUEVO OR
    @CARGO_ACTUAL <> @CARGO_NUEVO OR
    @SALUD_ACTUAL <> @SALUD_NUEVO OR
    @PENSION_ACTUAL <> @PENSION_NUEVO OR
    @ARL_ACTUAL <> @ARL_NUEVO OR
    @CAJA_ACTUAL <> @CAJA_NUEVO )

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_EMPLEADO (
ESTADO_EMPLEADO,
CODIGO_EMPLEADO,
TIPO_DOCUMENTO, 
ID_EMPLEADO,
CIUDAD_EXP_DOC,
NOMBRE_EMPLEADO,
FECHA_INGRESO,
FECHA_RETIRO,
TIPO_CONTRATO,
SALARIO,
TIPO_LABORES,
DEPENDENCIA,
CARGO,
SALUD,
PENSION,
ARL,
CAJA,
TIPO_ACTUALIZACION,
FECHA_ASIGNACION_LABORAL,
USUARIO,
NOMBRE_PC,
FECHA_ACTUALIZACION ) 
VALUES (
 @ESTADOEMPLEADO_NUEVO,
 @CODEMPLEADO,
 @TIPOID_NUEVO,
 @NUMEROID_NUEVO ,
 @CIUDADEXP_NUEVO,
 @NOMBREEMPLEADO,
 @FECHAI_NUEVO ,
 @FECHAR_NUEVO ,
 @TIPOCONTRATO_NUEVO,
 @SALARIO_NUEVO ,
 @TIPOLABORES_NUEVO, 
 @DEPENDENCIA_NUEVO ,
 @CARGO_NUEVO ,
 @SALUD_NUEVO ,
 @PENSION_NUEVO ,
 @ARL_NUEVO ,
 @CAJA_NUEVO,
@TIPOACTUALIZACION,
 @FECHA_ACTUALIZACION_LAB,
 @USUARIORESPONSABLE,
 @NOMBREPC,
 GETDATE())
 GO
```

El condicional If que estoy incluyendo para que determine si algunos de los campos sufrió cambio no esta realizando la condición, quiero saber que tengo mal en ese IF porque creo que allí puede estar el problema.
Gracias de corazón <3

Answer (score 1):

El trigger está mal concebido, porque estás tratando el mismo como si una sentencia update solo usara una fila y esto no es correcto, ya que update puede realizarlo en un conjunto. Por tanto no se asignan valores a variables, que solo pueden contener uno. Salvo que hagas bucles, pero no son buenos en lenguajes `sql` y además en este caso, no son necesarios.

Por otro lado tienes desordenados y sin valores la sentencia de inserción, puesto que hay variables que no has seteado.

El código debería de ser mucho más simple tal que:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TR_UPDATE_HISTORIAL_EMPLEADO

ON EMPLEADO FOR UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO HISTORIAL_EMPLEADO (
                    ....
                    --DEFINE TODAS LAS COLUMNAS POR ORDEN QUE QUIERAS
                    ) 
SELECT 
        --- EL EL CODIGO ANTERIOR, NO TIENES VALOR PARA ESTADO EMPLEADO 
        'ACTIVO',
        INSERTED.CODEMPLEADO,
        INSERTED.TIPO_DOCUMENTO ,
        ---- CARGA TODOS LOS VALORES POR ORDEN IDENTICO AL ORDEN QUE ESTABLECISTE EN LA DECLARACIÓN DE LA SENTENCIA INSERT.
        GETDATE()
 FROM INSERTED INNER JOIN DELETED ON INSERTED.ID = DELETED.ID 
 WHERE
        (INSERTED.CODEMPLEADO <> DELETED.CODEMPLEADO) OR 
        (INSERTED.CODEMPLEADO IS NULL AND DELETED.CODEMPLEADO IS NOT NULL) OR 
        (INSERTED.CODEMPLEADO IS NOT NULL AND DELTED.CODEMPLEADO IS NULL)
        -----
        OR
        (INSERTED.ESTADO_EMPLEADO<> DELETED.ESTADO_EMPLEADO) OR 
        (INSERTED.ESTADO_EMPLEADO IS NULL AND DELETED.ESTADO_EMPLEADO IS NOT NULL) OR 
        (INSERTED.ESTADO_EMPLEADOIS NOT NULL AND DELTED.ESTADO_EMPLEADO IS NULL)
        .....
 GO
```

Te falta definir los nombres de las columnas de la tabla `Historial_empleado`.
Las columnas de donde saldrán los datos. Inserted.columna o Deleted.columna.
Relacionar en ON la clave primaria de la tabla, tal que inserted.cod_empleado = deleted.cod_empleado o como se llame la columna **primary key**

Y luego por cada columna, si la definición de la misma no permite nulos, entonces con un distinto es suficiente, pero si permite nulos, tendrás que hacer lo mismo que yo te he puesto con `codEmpleado`.

| Inserted | Deleted |
| --- | --- |
| valor | valor |
| null | valor |
| valor | null |

[Trigger AFter Update ¿Cómo se hace?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/15/trigger-que-es-como-se-hace-y-como-funciona-after-for-update/)

Comment: La sentencia de inserción esta bien. Me di cuenta que en la validación del IF estaba validando la columna Tipo de Contrato con Tipo de Documento por eso siempre iba ejecutar el INSERT ya que el contenido de las columnas no tienen nada que ver porque siempre la información va ser diferente. Gracias por tu respuesta simplificaste bastante mi codigo.

Comment: Ya decía yo... Cómo Javi sabe tanto?... MCSA... Eso lo explica. Gracias Javi por tus aportes y compartir tus conocimientos con el sitio.

Comment: Supongo que estará bien. @estadoEmpleadoNuevo es siempre null, y un campo que tenga null. Además siempre hay que tener en cuenta esto: `Declare @a int; Declare @b int=5; select case when @a <> @b then 'si' else 'no' end;` Como verás a no es distinto de b si a es null o b es null

Comment: @Arriel gracias por el comentario.